# Vaadin Table.setCurrentPageFirstItemId does not work with Chrome

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm developing an application in Vaadin 7. I have a table and after refreshing the table content I want to maintain the scroll position.

So before updating the table I am getting the current selected item via:

```
Object firstItem = table.getCurrentPageFirstItemId();
```

After refreshing the table I am trying to set the index via:

```
table.setCurrentPageFirstItemId(firstItem);
```

This is working fine in IE and Firefox, but not in Chrome. It depends on the position of the scrollbar of the table. If the bar is over 50% down, then it does not work in Chrome.

Any ideas why it is not working?
I can't upgrade to Vaadin 8 (I don't know if this is fixed in Vaadin 8)

Comment: Any chance to upgrade to v8?

Comment: @André Schild No thats the problem. Do you think this should be fixed in v8?

Comment: If it's fixed, chances are that it's in v8 (Or that it will be fixed in v8 if you open an issue)

Comment: Well thats bad, because we cant upgrade :(

Comment: You will see this more often in the future, so upgrading will be a good idea. What might help you, is when you compare the v7 + v8 sources and perhaps you will find the fix which was done...

Comment: Alright, thank you very much.

Comment: I have the same problem with vaadin 7. Does a vaadin upgrade fix this issue?